# Reading file from by InputStream object

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I am trying to read text file whilst running the program from a jar archive.
I come accros that I need to use InputStream to read file. The snippet of code:

```
buffer = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream((getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("English_names.txt").getPath())));


System.out.println(buffer.read()+" yeas");
```

At this line `System.out.println(buffer.read()+" yeas");` program stops and nothing happens since then. Once you output the contents of `buffer` object it is not null.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Your first line seems a little convoluted. Where lies "English_names.txt"?

Comment: At this stage it lies within project's directory.

Comment: Great news, I have tried FileInputStream to pass into InputStream, and it works fine now. Hopefully it works whilst you run the app within by  using jar file. That was the aim of using InputStream

Comment: No. You should keep getResourceAsStream. Just use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("English_names.txt")` directly (if the file is in the base of your classpath.

Comment: "Within project directory" means the root of your source/class files (/src -> /bin or /classes) or its parent directory?

Comment: The file is within bin directory and one level down (Project/bin) -> Project

Comment: There's no reason for that to block unless the JAR file is on a problematic network drive. Are you sure it isn't throwing a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`InputStream#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29):

> This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

So basically, the stream appears to be waiting on content. I'm guessing it's how you've constructed the stream, you can simplify your construction to:

```
InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/English_names.txt");
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(resourceStream);
```

I'd also check to make sure that `resourceStream` is not-null.

Comment: You are right 'resourceStream' is null. But what is the problem, the file is in there...

Comment: @uml: in this case, `getResourceAsStream` is used to get files that are *on the classpath*. If you want to open a file not on the classpath, perhaps you should check out `FileInputStream`.

Comment: /D:/Aristotelis/J-A-V-A/Msc_project/code/branches/Crypto/bin/English_names.txt Tha is the path returned by some method. Why is there '/' in front of D partition? Is that okay?

Comment: @uml: cool, try adding a slash (modified my answer): `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/English_names.txt");`

Comment: No, it does not help. The file is within project's directory. That should mean it is on the classpath.

Comment: @uml: no, being in the same directory as the project is not the same as being on the classpath. How are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about `InputStream` being `null` when passed into `BufferedInputStream` constructor since it, the constructor handles `null` parameters just fine. When supplied with `null` it will just return `null` without throwing any exception. Also since `InputStream` implements `AutoClosable` the `try-with-resources` block will take care of closing your streams properly.

```
try (
        final InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/English_names.txt");
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ) {
        if (null == bis)
            throw new IOException("requsted resource was not found");
        // Do your reading. 
        // Do note that if you are using InputStream.read() you may want to call it in a loop until it returns -1
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Either resource is not found or other I/O error occurred 
    }
```